# uploading the name of the images

Tags: php, mysql

I'm uploading the name of the images to the database!

The problem is that the name is in the database with a blank space before the name!

Where is the problem?

```
$original_name = strtolower(trim($arquivo['name']));
$caracteres = array("ç","~","^","]","[","{","}",";",":","´",",",">",
                   "<","-","/","|","@","$","%","ã","â","á","à","é",
                  "è","ó","§","ò","+","=","*","&","(",")","!","#","?",
                  "`","ã"," ","©","£");

$original_name = str_replace(' ', '', $original_name);
$final_name = str_replace($caracteres,"",$original_name);
```

Comment: can you show us the query which is inserting the record in the database?

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO arquivos (nome, tipo, data, hora, item) VALUES (' ".$final_name." ','".$tipo_arquivo."', CURDATE(), NOW(), ' ".$idItem."')");

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use white list of allowed characters such as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

And use:

```
$final_name = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9_]+#i", "", $arquivo['name']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I added it and is equal

Comment: then, you add that space when inserting the value to db

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO arquivos (nome, tipo, data, hora, item) VALUES (' ".$final_name." ','".$tipo_arquivo."', CURDATE(), NOW(), ' ".$idItem."')");